# Change UIToolbar color above UIKeyboard iOS 7 color

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitoolbar, uikeyboard

i'm trying to change color of a UIToolbar above the keyboard, but I can not recreate the color black semi transparent keyboard, i have tried this:

```
alertToolBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.5f];
```

but this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alertToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;`

That should give the iOS 7 Blur that you are looking for. Don't tint the toolbar, just set the tool bar style.